# Does "invervjuo" cover all meanings of the English word "interview"?

Tags: word-meaning, meaning

In German, the loanword "Interview" is mostly used for when a reporter, journalist or maker of a documentary interviews someone for the media/medium they're working for. A job interview however is traditionally called "Bewerbungsgespräch" (verbatim: ~ 'application conversation') and has AFAIK only recently (due to influence of English in anything business-related) began to sometimes be called "Interview" in German, too, which (also AFAIK) isn't (yet?) considered standard usage.

On Duolingo

> Tomorrow I will have an interview for a position at a bank.

[is translated](https://forum.duolingo.com/comment/31844838) as

> Morgaŭ mi havos intervjuon por posteno en banko.

So it seems that Esperanto uses "invervjuo" in the same (wide) meaning as English uses "inverview", or at least one that covers job interviews, too, not just by-/for-media interviews. Is the Esperanto Duolingo sentence idiomatic, though?

**Is "invervjuo" used for all kinds of "inverview" / for all meanings the English word "interview" has?** Does it cover job interviews, too, as the Duolingo sentence suggests?

Comment: French makes the same distinction between “un interview” and “un entretien (d’embauche)”.

Comment: I guess the latter is a job interview?

Comment: Yes, it seems to be the same as the German words.

Comment: Reta Vortaro: _Interparolo konsistanta el demandoj kaj respondoj pri ies vivo, agoj aŭ opinioj por raporto_. Taking _raporto_ loosely, yes, all meanings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, nowadays *invervjuo* is used in the sense of *job interview*, too, also by sources other than Duolingo.

One example from many:

> Ses personoj kandidatis por la posteno de ĝenerala direktoro de UEA, anoncita de la 
>   estraro de la asocio en februaro 2015.
>   Tri kandidatoj estis elektitaj por personaj intervjuoj...
>   (http://www.liberafolio.org/arkivo/www.liberafolio.org/2015/veronika-poor-nova-generala-direktoro-de-uea/)

In my youth, I would have called such an interview a *dungocela interparolo,* 
but ***intervjuo*** became the standard term several years ago, doubtless because of its English equivalent.